# Selecting n elements from array in sublinear time and subquadratic compute and memory complexity using indices

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

Are GPUs or CPUs capable of selecting n elements from an array in sublinear time using indices? If so, what would be some good alternatives to achieve this?

Lets say I have an array A = {1, 5, 6, 3, 6, 2} and indices I = {2, 5, 2, 4, 1, 0}. The resulting array should be: B = {6, 2, 6, 6, 5, 1}. The time complexity for this should be sublinear with respect to the length of I.

edit: sorry I forgot to mention that the memory and compute complexity should be subquadratic. For instance you could retrieve the elements in constant time if you would out of the indices construct a matrix "C" of one-hot encoded column vectors and perform a vector-matrix multiplication A*C.

Comment: Well practically no, because if one thread would do the task it would obviously require $O(n)$ operations but if you have multiple threads available you could use the main thread to create $\sqrt{n}$ child threads who each take care of $\sqrt{n}$ indices. The problem is that you don't have infinitly many threads so this only works up to a certain $n$.
The last approach describe would have a theoretically complexity of $O(\sqrt{n})$(assuming infinitely many threads).

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer unless you describe a particular abstract model of "GPU" and "CPU". Otherwise, it is really a hardware question. Perhaps current CPUs aren't able, but future ones would be. Also, the answer really depends on what values of $n$ you are aiming at (in practice), which suggests that it's not a good fit here.

Comment: In reality, the bottleneck may well be memory access rather than GPU/CPU processing power.